# Laravel 5.0 bulk update

Tags: php, laravel, bulk

I would like to execute multiple update statements rather than executing them individually in order to avoid multiple DB hits.Following is the code

```
$updateStatement = '';
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $i++;
        $updateStatement = $updateStatement. "update users set packet_seqno = '".$i."' where id = ".$user->id . ';  ';      
    }
    \DB::statement($updateStatement);
```

However, it is not working and throwing error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update

Can you please help me to fix this?

Here is the dump of the $updateStatement.

```
"update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '1' where id = 37;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '2' where id = 39;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '3' where id = 40;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '4' where id = 42;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '5' where id = 43;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '6' where id = 44;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '7' where id = 45;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '8' where id = 46;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '9' where id = 47;  update ppt_import_mortgage1 set packet_seqno = '10' where id = 48;  "
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use eloquent, you could simply do this:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
       $i++;
    User::where('id',$user->id)->update(['packet_seqno' => $i]);
}
```

or better:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
       $i++;
    $user->update(['packet_seqno' => $i]);
}
```

Comment: That's one query per user - this is what OP is trying to avoid with bulk update

Comment: okay. thats true, in that case its better OP uses raw SQL, but how are we going to get value of  ` $i++;` and `$user->id` without multiple loops... I thinks that's where the problem lies, because even with raw sql you still need those loops

Comment: @Digitlimit: I would like to run all the update statements at once, so that the database hits are minimized, the above examples will hit the database for each query, that is what I'm trying to avoid using the bulk update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$updateStatement = '';
   foreach ($users as $user) {
       $i++;
       $updateStatement = "update users set packet_seqno = '".$i."' where id = ".$user->id; 
    \DB::update(\DB::raw($updateStatement));     
}
```

See, if that helps.